# Slow down / speed up any arbitary process

Tags: windows, process

Is it possible on windows, to slow down and/or speed up a process as and when i see the need arise (One way i can think of is to dynamically change how much processor time a process gets). Please help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you were hoping for something else, you'll need to give us another hint. Like maybe add a language tag.

Comment: @CodyGray my question is language agnostic, if it is possible for a certain language please do write it as an answer.

Comment: My point is that the question cannot reasonably be language agnostic, except for the simple answer "Yes, it is possible". The way to do it is going to depend on what language you're using. And this site doesn't work very well if every answer picks a random different language.

Comment: @CodyGray i would randomly pick C/C++, because that is what i would expect most of my target programs to be coded in.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **process priority** and/or the **processor affinity** (i.e. the list of processors the process might use). You can't do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the priority when you starting the process in Windows, you can use **start** command.

```
START ["title"] [/Dpath] [/I] [/MIN] [/MAX] [/SEPARATE | /SHARED][/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL][/WAIT] [/B] [command/program][parameters]
```

You can assign priority by choosing one of options below

```
/LOW | /NORMAL | /HIGH | /REALTIME | /ABOVENORMAL | /BELOWNORMAL
```

If you want more explanations of this command, just go to
http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm

Comment: The OP said "as the need arises", which presumably means *not* before the process has even started.